# taking image on touching screen in android

Tags: android

I am following google's android developer guide to create camera capturing app.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

I have created CameraPreview class to display live images from camera. and then attaching camera to it as below

```
// Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
// Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
```

In the example the image is clicked as user presses button as below:-

```
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(
 new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get an image from the camera
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }
}
```

);

Can I somehow set touch listener to camera preview ( screen) such that as the user touches screen I can get the coordinates of the touch and then do my separate processing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raplace:

```
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get an image from the camera
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }
});
```

with:

```
preview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {     
Log.i("onTouch","onTouch event:"+event.getAction());

switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        // get an image from the camera
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

        // coordinates
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        Log.i("onTouch", "ACTION_DOWN");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

});

Comment: the line        preview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()         is showing error as        "The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){})"

Comment: **add:** `import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;import android.view.View;` **Or** change to: `setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener)`